# How can I convert multidimensional array into 2 dimensions array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

Given multidimensional array (of any size and depth):

```
const multidimensionalArray = [1, [2, [3, [4, [5]]]], [6], [7, [8], [9]]];
```

I need to convert it into 2 dimensions array following example below (the idea is that each nested value should be converted into an array of all parents + this value).

Expected 2 dimensions array :

```
const twoDimensionsArray = [
  [1],
  [1, 2],
  [1, 2, 3],
  [1, 2, 3, 4],
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
  [1, 6],
  [1, 7],
  [1, 7, 8],
  [1, 7, 9],
];
```

Could you please help me to solve the problem?

Comment: @GuerricP, you are right about dimension, already updated the description. And  "strange numbers" might be of any type, it doesn't matter.

Comment: What's the criteria if the data can be of any type? It's helpful to have a copy+pasteable example to work with, and `1.1.*` isn't valid.

Comment: @Phix I'll update the example... But the idea is that each nested value should be converted into an array of all parents + this value, for example: [1] => [ [1] ];   [1, [2] ] => [ [1], [1, 2] ]; [1, [2], [3]] => [[1], [1, 2], [1, 3]] ...

Comment: Please include any research you've done on the subject and any attempts you've made based on that research. See [ask].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A [recursive](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Recursion) call for each nested array ought to do the trick.

NOTE: The following may not be complete for your use case - your data needs to be in a specific order for this to work - but I think this should be clean enough as an example:

```js
const customFlatten = (arr, parents = [], output = []) => {
  for (const item of arr) {
    // If not an array...
    if (!Array.isArray(item)) {
      parents.push(item) // update parents for recursive calls
      output.push(parents.slice(0)) // add entry to output (copy of _parents)

    // If an array...
    } else {
      customFlatten(item, parents.slice(0), output) // recursive call
    }
  }
  return output
}

console.log(customFlatten([1, [2, [3, [4, [5]]]], [6], [7, [8], [9]]]))
```